# How to check view exist or not?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter I am trying to check before loading the view that the file exist or not from controller, I tried like-

```
public function foo($file = "")
{
    if (file_exists(APPPATH."views/log/{$file}.".EXT))
    {
        $this->load->view('log/'.$file);
    }
    else
        show_404();
}
```

But the file is exist there then also the `file_exists()` method is returning `false`, I have checked it using `var_dump()` also. I am not getting what is the problem here, I am guessing that there is something problem related to mapping because the directory structure is like-

```
application
   |--controllers
   |  |--ctrl.php   //Controller file where I am checking
   |--views
      |--log
         |-- .. //Checking files for here
```

but how can I resolve?

Edit: Just mistyped 'views' to 'view'(in code where I am calling `file_exists()` method in `if`) corrected it.

Comment: Srry tht was typing mistake but problem is still there

Comment: Please post the correct code, show how you are calling `foo()`, how you are passing parameters to it, and the result of your `var_dump()`.

Comment: Case matters, view file names should be in lowercase

Comment: Controller name is 'test' so i am loading the page say `http://localhost/myapp/test/foo/viewfile` and I the file `viewfile.php` is exist in `application/views/log/`

Comment: @WesleyMurch it's having `application/views/log/viewfile.php`

Comment: argh, i mistyped view / views as well, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `EXT` constant in Codeigniter is equal to `.php` and defined in `index.php`:

```
// The PHP file extension
// this global constant is deprecated.
define('EXT', '.php');
```

You are adding an extra dot:

```
APPPATH."views/log/{$file}.".EXT
//                        ^
```

Which would result in something like `views/log/myfile..php`

Since the constant is being phased out you should avoid it.

Comment: no, I have printed the result of `APPPATH."views/log/{$file}.".EXT`. It's having `application/views/log/viewfile.php` as I have mentioned in the comment above. but then also it's not working

Comment: Unless you have changed the constant definition that seems impossible given your code. Also, `APPPATH` should be a full server path so that doesn't add up, you are showing a relative path. Please show *exactly* how you are checking the value, [edit] your post.

Comment: Oh yes! it's working now :). But when I have printed the value of `APPPATH."views/log/{$file}.".EXT` then it was giving `application/views/log/viewfile.php`. I don't know what was the problem but any way thanks :)

Comment: So, Gremlins were the issue I assume.

Comment: Nah! It's just I figured right now, while I was echoing the value of above code instead of writing `echo APPPATH."views/log/{$file}.".EXT` I have written `echo APPPATH."views/log/{$file}.php"` that was the mistake and next line I was updating only in which I have written `var_dump(file_exists(APPPATH."views/docs/{$file}.".EXT))`. It was the problem.

Comment: It would have made more sense to assign it to a variable, then check the value of that variable. OK, best of luck moving forward.